# How to select only *columns* with more than one distinct value?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-12

`SELECT DISTINCT …` removes duplicate rows. Is there any way to remove duplicate *columns,* that is, columns where every value is the same? I'm looking through a legacy schema for the "distinguishing features" of some rows, so this would be super helpful. If it makes it any easier all of the columns are simple types like `INT`, `TEXT` and `TIMESTAMP`. Basically, given a table like this:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE column_test
(
    foo TEXT,
    bar INT,
    baz BOOLEAN,
    bat TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE
);

INSERT INTO column_test (
    foo, bar, baz, bat
) VALUES
    ('lorem ipsum', 1, TRUE, '2000-01-01 UTC'),
    ('lorem ipsum', 2, TRUE, '2000-01-01 UTC'),
    ('other', 3, TRUE, '2000-01-01 UTC');
```

is it possible to write a query which will select only the `foo` and `bar` columns, since those are the only columns with more than one value? Something like this:

```
SELECT columns_with_more_than_one_value(*) FROM column_test;
foo           bar
'lorem ipsum' 1
'lorem ipsum' 2
'other'       3
```

---

I guess one way would be to `SELECT *`, transpose the result, remove any rows where all the values are the same, then transpose again, but that would be very complex and I don't know how I would keep the original column names in the result.

Comment: Please show us the result that you expect.

Comment: is this maybe a job for whatever is processing the data - select all the candidate columns then write a non-sql script to process the results to filter out those columns?

Comment: @micsthepick That would be a last resort, since it would not integrate nicely with my IDE and would make casual exploration 10x slower.

Comment: A standard SQL statement must return a *fixed* number of columns. So what you ask for basically requires dynamic SQL, which makes the task much more oomplex.

Comment: @GMB Well, it is technically a fixed number of columns, except the set of columns isn't known until some of the data has been inspected. And the complexity is why I asked :)

Comment: @l0b0: that's the point. Standard SQL requires the number of columns to be known before the statement is executed.

Comment: Oh, it doesn't have to be at all portable, if that's any help.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you cannot select unknown columns from a table. A query result must have a structure defined before it is executed. What you can do is to create a (temporary) view that contains expected columns. The function below does the job, extensively using [dynamic SQL.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) The first argument of the function is a table name, the second - the name of the temporary view to be created.

```
create or replace function create_view_with_distinct_columns(text, text)
returns void language plpgsql as $$
declare
    col text;
    ct int;
    list text = '';
begin
    for col in 
        execute format('
            select attname
            from pg_attribute
            where attrelid = %s
            and attnum > 0',
            $1::regclass::oid)
    loop
        execute format('
            select count(distinct %I)
            from %I',
            col, $1)
        into ct;
        if ct > 1 then
            list:= format('%s%s,', list, col);
        end if;
    end loop;
    execute format('
        create temp view %I as
        select %s
        from %I',
        $2, left(list, -1), $1);
end $$;
```

Use:

```
select create_view_with_distinct_columns('column_test', 'column_view');

select * from column_view;

     foo     | bar
-------------+-----
 lorem ipsum |   1
 lorem ipsum |   2
 other       |   3
(3 rows)
```

[Db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=19f1534d1501b35741e2a319aeb88f39)